# Parsing XML with 'nil' attributes and empty 'element' tags using 'xmlbf'

Tags: xml, haskell

I'm trying to parse an XML API response into Haskell datatypes.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60691469/parsing-xml-response-using-servant-client-and-servant-xml) I asked earlier.

Using [xmlbf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmlbf) library.

This is an example response

```xml
<GoodreadsResponse>
  <Request>
    <authentication>true</authentication>
    <key>api_key</key>
    <method>search_index</method>
  </Request>
  <search>
    <query>Ender's Game</query>
    <results-start>1</results-start>
    <results-end>20</results-end>
    <source>Goodreads</source>
    <results>
      <work>
        <id type="integer">2422333</id>
        <books_count type="integer">252</books_count>
        <ratings_count type="integer">1070421</ratings_count>
        <text_reviews_count type="integer">42249</text_reviews_count>
        <original_publication_year type="integer">1985</original_publication_year>
        <original_publication_month type="integer" nil="true"/>
        <original_publication_day type="integer" nil="true"/>
        <average_rating>4.30</average_rating>
        <best_book type="Book">
          <id type="integer">375802</id>
          <title>Ender's Game (Ender's Saga, #1)</title>
          <author>
            <id type="integer">589</id>
            <name>Orson Scott Card</name>
          </author>
        </best_book>
      </work>
      <work>
        <id type="integer">938064</id>
        <books_count type="integer">64</books_count>
        <ratings_count type="integer">82572</ratings_count>
        <text_reviews_count type="integer">867</text_reviews_count>
        <original_publication_year type="integer">1984</original_publication_year>
        <original_publication_month type="integer">12</original_publication_month>
        <original_publication_day type="integer" nil="true"/>
        <average_rating>4.18</average_rating>
        <best_book type="Book">
          <id type="integer">44687</id>
          <title>Enchanters' End Game (The Belgariad, #5)</title>
          <author>
          </author>
        </best_book>
      </work>
    </results>
  </search>
</GoodreadsResponse>
```

and I want to parse it into this

```hs
data GoodreadsBookAuthor =
  GoodreadsBookAuthor -- <author> element.
    { goodreadsBookAuthorID   :: Text
    , goodreadsBookAuthorName :: Text
    }
  deriving (Show)

data GoodreadsBook =
  GoodreadsBook -- <best_book> element.
    { goodreadsBookID     :: Text
    , goodreadsBookTitle  :: Text
    , goodreadsBookAuthor :: Maybe GoodreadsBookAuthor -- Could be empty or missing.
    }
  deriving (Show)

data GoodreadsWork =
  GoodreadsWork -- <work> element.
    { goodreadsWorkID               :: Text
    -- Ignore <books_count> element.
    , goodreadsWorkRatingCount      :: Text
    -- Ignore <text_reviews_count> element.
    , goodreadsWorkPublicationYear  :: Maybe Int -- Could be missing.
    , goodreadsWorkPublicationMonth :: Maybe Int -- Could be missing.
    , goodreadsWorkPublicationDay   :: Maybe Int -- Could be missing.
    , goodreadsWorkAverageRating    :: Text
    }
  deriving (Show)

newtype GoodreadsSearchResults =
  GoodreadsSearchResults -- <results> element.
    { goodreadsWorks :: [GoodreadsWork]
    }

data GoodreadsSearch =
  GoodreadsSearch -- <search> element.
    { goodreadsSearchQuery        :: Text
    , goodreadsSearchResultsStart :: Text
    , goodreadsSearchResultsEnd   :: Text
    -- Ignore <source></source>
    , goodreadsSearchResults      :: GoodreadsSearchResults
    }
  deriving (Show)

data GoodreadsRequest =
  GoodreadsRequest -- <Request> element.
    { authentication :: Text
    , key            :: Text
    , method         :: Text
    }
  deriving (Show)

data GoodreadsResponse =
  GoodreadsResponse -- <GoodreadsResponse> element.
    { goodreadsRequest :: GoodreadsRequest
    , goodreadsSearch  :: GoodreadsSearch
    }
  deriving (Show)
```

These are the `instance` derivations I have wrote so far

```hs
instance FromXml GoodreadsRequest where
  fromXml =
    pElement "Request"
      $   GoodreadsRequest
      <$> pElement "authentication" pText
      <*> pElement "key"            pText
      <*> pElement "method"         pText

instance FromXml GoodreadsBookAuthor where
  fromXml =
    pElement "author"
      $   GoodreadsBookAuthor
      <$> pElement "id"   pText
      <*> pElement "name" pText

instance FromXml GoodreadsBook where
  fromXml =
    pElement "best_book"
      $   GoodreadsBook
      <$> pElement "id"    pText
      <*> pElement "title" pText
      <*> fromXml

instance FromXml GoodreadsWork where
  fromXml =
    pElement "work"
      $   GoodreadsWork
      <$> pElement "id"                         pText -- kept Text for simplicity
      <*> pElement "ratings_count"              pText -- kept Text for simplicity
      <*> pElement "original_publication_year"  pText -- isn't handling missing value.
      <*> pElement "original_publication_month" pText -- isn't handling missing value.
      <*> pElement "original_publication_day"   pText -- isn't handling missing value.
      <*> pElement "average_rating"             pText -- kept Text for simplicity

instance FromXml GoodreadsSearchResults where
  fromXml = pElement "results" $ GoodreadsSearchResults <$> many fromXml

instance FromXml GoodreadsSearch where
  fromXml =
    pElement "search"
      $   GoodreadsSearch
      <$> pElement "query"              pText
      <*> pElement "results-start"      pText
      <*> pElement "results-end"        pText
      <*> fromXml

instance FromXml GoodreadsResponse where
  fromXml =
    pElement "GoodreadsResponse" $ GoodreadsResponse <$> fromXml <*> fromXml
```

What I want to know is how should I handle missing values like these

```xml
<original_publication_month type="integer" nil="true"/>
<original_publication_day type="integer" nil="true"/>
```

and empty element tags like these

```xml
<author>
</author>
```

some of those values should be parsed to `Int` or `Double` but I have kept them as `Text` for simplicity.

Comment: Normally, you would represent missing results with `Maybe Int` or `Maybe Text`. Are you asking how you would parse that?

Comment: Yes, I would want to use `Either` or `Maybe` type but I'm not sure how to do that. Like in `aeson` you can use `.:?` to parse into a `Maybe` type. I'm looking for a way to replicate `.:?` but for `XML`.

Comment: Like this line in the `instance` declaration `<*> pElement "original_publication_month" pText`, I'm looking for a way to do something like this `<*> pElement "original_publication_month" pMaybeText` so the `parser` wouldn't fail and return `[]`.

Comment: There is a parser verb `element'`, which returns `Either String Node`, that you could map to a `Maybe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle an empty element, try defining a combinator that parses either a text node or, just as happily, there being nothing in the element at all. Perhaps `pMaybeText = optional pText` is what you're after, where `optional contents = fmap Just contents <|> pure Nothing` or imported from `Control.Applicative`.

In general, <|> separates alternative grammars. The combinator before <|> will first be tried, and if it can't parse the input, the combinator after it will be given a chance.